# Changing the output of my HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to create a form using data from MySQL and my current output is not looking as expected so I just need some simple changes to my current form

My current output in the browser: http://gyazo.com/f4668ca59586ec0d4d1500ea6f7b6257

What I am looking to do is

- fix the problem with the first column called 'Long Jump A' so its
  next to a drop down menu, and you can see the bottom one is next to
  nothing.
- Secondly, How can I swap the order of the drop down and the
  event? So the event is on the left then the drop down is on the
  right?
- Moving the form down from the top so there is a space

The code:

```
<?php

    require_once 'db/connect.php';

        //Query to display all events                           
            if ($event_result = $con->query("SELECT Event.Name FROM event")) {  
                echo "<form method =\"POST\">";
                            while ($row = $event_result->fetch_assoc()) {               
                            echo $row['Name'] . ' <br> ';

                                if ($student_result = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Student.Forename, Student.Surname, Student_ID " .
                                    "FROM Student, Teacher " .
                                        "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Form = 'C'")) {

                                    if ($student_result->num_rows) {                
                                                echo "<select name ='Student_ID'>";                     
                                                    while ($row1 = $student_result->fetch_assoc()) {                                        
                                                    echo "<option value ='" . $row1['Student_ID'] . "'>" . $row1['Forename'] . ' ' . $row1['Surname'] . "</option>";
                                                }
                                                echo "</select>";                   
                                    }                                                                   
                                }
                            }   

                echo "</form>"; 
            }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an opening `<br />` as you echo out the name of the row.  This means echo the title, then break before you display the `<select>` group.   You should move that `<br />` down right before the closing while loop.

Or just remove the top `<Br />` and add it back after the ending  so it looks like this:

```
 echo "</select> <br />";
```

edit: this will fix the last two of your questions, as now each select group will properly line up with the title of the row.  If you want more space at the top of the form you have a bunch of options: add more breaks, add a margin or padding, or position the element as relative and use css top property or CSS transforms to move it.

Comment: this did not work: echo "</select> <br />"; that created an output like this: http://gyazo.com/3d6fd00a2f6faeb5c2f772fbb1419144

Comment: Hmm.. you can add some CSS to the select element such as: style="display:inline-block;" or you can float left the select.  Or you can use tables / a grid layout.

Comment: thanks joey, i need to now add a space between the event and the drop-down (currently they are merged next to each other) and then move the form down a little

Comment: Add &nbsp; after you echo the $row['name'];  That will give you blank space... you can use as many &nbsp; as you want... this is a hacky solution... but ideally you would be best served by learning some CSS.